# Empathy auto accept group chat invite

Tags: empathy

I'm using empathy 2.34.0 as chat client for account hosted on Google app (server talk.google.com). I'm happy with the features that empathy provides and integration with Google chat, however for group chat when the request is received I need to click on "join" button showed in popup to get started. This makes sense but I would to know if there is any way to automatically join the chat room without clicking the "join" button as I use it only with trusted uses. Besides the messages shared after the invite request and before my entry to chat room is not accessible to me. I looked around the empathy settings but couldn't find anything useful, wondering if I can get some help from here. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=60767